# How to properly find and link NDK shaderc lib into your project in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, cmake, android-ndk, linker

I want to run **Vulkan** on my android phone, and currently, I'm stuck at the point trying to make CMake find the `libshaderc`.

What I did is first build the shaderc:

```
cd <my-ndk-root>/sources/third_party/shaderc
../../../ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=. APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=Android.mk APP_STL:=c++_static APP_ABI=all NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION:=clang libshaderc_combined -j16
```

And inside my `CMakeLists.txt`, I have:

```
get_filename_component(SHADERC_SRC
    ${ANDROID_NDK}/sources/third_party/shaderc
    ABSOLUTE)
add_library(shaderc_lib STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(shaderc_lib PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
    ${SHADERC_SRC}/libs/${ANDROID_STL}/${ANDROID_ABI}/libshaderc.a)
```

But the CMake can't find the shaderc_lib, and failed with error:

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:

shaderc_lib
```

Please note that I already checked that I have `libshaderc.a` under the `[my-ndk-root]/sources/third_party/shaderc/libs`:

```
 .
└── c++_static
    ├── arm64-v8a
    │   └── libshaderc.a
    ├── armeabi-v7a
    │   └── libshaderc.a
    ├── x86
    │   └── libshaderc.a
    └── x86_64
        └── libshaderc.a

5 directories, 4 files
```

I'm not very familiar with CMake and NDK, so if I made some stupid mistakes, please correct me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to assign **hardcoded** (no variables) path to the `IMPORTED_LOCATION` property? You also may print your path via `message()` command and check that it is expected one.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Hi thanks for your comment but I tried print the IMPORTED_LOCATION, and it's as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your CMake path points to the correct place. Also, your `libshaderc.a` is static library and you need to link it to your shared lib, e.g. `libshaderc-shared.so` using below CMake configuration:

```
target_link_libraries( libshaderc-shared
                   [my-ndk-root]/sources/third_party/shaderc/libs/c++_static/${ANDROID_ABI}/libshaderc.a )
```

**References:**

- Here is the guide for how to properly build **shaderc** https://github.com/google/shaderc.
- https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/graphics/shader-compilers

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply! I tried your suggestion, but still cmake think libshadercd-shared is NOTFOUND.

Comment: Ha, I think I understand what you means. I should directly target_link_libraries(native-lib libshaderc.a) instead of target_link_libraries(shaderc-shared libshaderc.a) then target_link_libraries(native-lib shaderc-shared). This solve my problem. Thanks!

Comment: I have to say I'm still confused about why the add library imported not working. Cmake says it "references a library file located outside the project." and I'm setting the correct imported location, how come cmake can't find it? Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Your path setting is not correct for the import lib, try to print the path to verify its correctness

Comment: `${ANDROID_NDK}` can be used for ndk root.

Answer (score 0):

I am busy learning Vulkan as well, and the only help I can currently provide is the vulkan samples. They work on an android device which supports vulkan. I am using a nokia scirocco 8 as my test device. Have a look at the CMakeLists.txt in the samples as to how to link the shaderc static library. https://github.com/googlesamples/vulkan-basic-samples/